# How to change background attribute with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css

This quite simply does not work for me!

```
$("#about").mouseleave(function(){
                $("#about").css("background", 'transparent url("../resources/about.png") no-repeat top left;');
            });
```

I have a div working as a button, when clicked it opens a window. More relevantly, when clicked its background is swapped out for a smaller image via css `.mouseDown` in order to give the impression of a button being depressed.

But I'm trying to make it automatically go back to the bigger image if you drag the mouse out of the div without releasing the click. As it is, it just stays as the smaller image. It's an edge case, but I want to fix it.

Why doesn't the above code work? I tried `.prop`, `.css`....I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: use css() for style property

Comment: He said he tried .css

Comment: use `.css()` and take the `;` out from `left;`

Comment: BINGO....semi-colon for the lose.

Comment: Yep - next time open the console via dev tools when viewing the page to debug.  That kind of syntax error will jump right out!

Comment: Haven't had my coffee yet. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `.css()` and also take out the semicolon from the value you want to assign:

```
$("#about").mouseleave(function(){
     $("#about").css("background", 'transparent url("../resources/about.png") no-repeat top left');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

background is not an attribute, but css :

```
$("#about").mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).css('background', 'transparent url("../resources/about.png") no-repeat top left');
});
```

Comment: Since I already tried that, I edited it to make things more accurate. There must be another problem.

Comment: Well, it works just fine in [*jsfiddle*](http://jsfiddle.net/UzR5L/) so you must be doing something else wrong then. Note that I removed the semicolon when I first posted the answer, so you obviously didn't try it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `css` instead of `attr`. `background` is not a property of the element itself but it is a css property for the element. And remove the semi column at the end of the css prop value.

```
$(this).css("background", 'transparent url("../resources/about.png") no-repeat top left');
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sPfp5/)**

Comment: I edited it to make things more accurate, lol. There must be another problem.

Comment: Yup. It is. I noticed it while preparing a fiddle..:)

Answer (score 1):

You should delete `top left` styles. It's works for me very fine.